# Is it advisable (safe) to freeze water based paint brushes in lieu of cleaning?

Tags: painting

What's a safe (for brushes) way to save them for a day without cleaning them, when using water based (latex) paint?

I've heard:

> We’re in the middle of painting the entire inside of a two-bedroom house right now, and thought we would share one of our favorite
> painting tricks. If you’re using latex paint, brushes and rollers can
> be frozen overnight, saving you the arduous task of cleaning them
> until you’re done with the project.
>
> Simply **put the brush or roller into a plastic bag and stick it in
> the freezer.** When you’re ready to start painting again, all you have
> to do is take it out and let it thaw. We’ve successfully re-frozen and
> re-thawed the same brush several times, the trick is not to forget
> about it when it’s thawing – too long out of the freezer and the paint
> on it will start to dry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I do freeze brushes and rollers, and paint pots as well.  But only with 2-part epoxy or LPU paints since it slows cure.  They are uncleanable; it would take more of their $30/gal solvent to clean them than the brush is worth.

Also, we have a freezer dedicated to this, the fumes are pungent.  I have successfully used a sealing Rubbermaid container for that purpose.

On latex/emulsion paint, it makes less sense to me for a couple of reasons.  First, the paint base is  water, which not only freezes in the freezer, but expands when it does.  I do not see how the paint in the brush would not be degraded.  Second, cleaning up after latex is so crazy easy that I don't see it saving much time.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't frozen my brushes or roller covers before so I can't speak on the effectiveness of that.

I typically wrap my brushes, roller covers and even my buckets in plastic. I have an 18" roller cover that is wrapped in plastic right now, I've been using it off and on for the last week or so. When wrapping brushes I make sure to wet the brush well and then wrap it tight, not so much that is deforms the bristles but enough to keep the air out.